# Lock screen not prompting for password

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

If I lock using Super+L, my screen is locked. However, if the screen remains locked for too long, when I come back I drag up to type in my password, my password is never requested and the screen is completely unlocked.

As well as that, the screen blanks out if I don't move my mouse every 30 seconds or so.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I had enabled password-less login with auto login enabled and now I can't get it to prompt me anymore. Seems like a bug as setting auto login to false isn't being applied.

Answer (score 0):

About screen Lock you can change it in Settings->Privacy->Screen Lock. 
Also if you want Password on every Login, then you need to change it in Settings->Details->User->Automatic Login set to off.

Comment: Automatic login was already off. The screen briefly flashes that dark purple pattern on the bottom-center of the screen before unlocking when it should have asked for the password.